# How to create a CCNet Label with multiple labellers?

Tags: ccnet-config

I am using ccnet 1.6 and want to create CCNetLabel with following format

> M.m.b.r
>   Where
>         M is fixed text,
>         m is from **Default Labeller**,
>         b is from **File Labeller**,
>         r is svn revision

I want value as CCNetLabel as it is used by svn control block when tagging the build.

Comment: This question sounds related to [*Is there a way to use the revision of the Date Labeller in a Default Labeller?*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18355916/is-there-a-way-to-use-the-revision-of-the-date-labeller-in-a-default-labeller). Maybe some answers are valid here, as well?