# Is there a way to use the revision of the Date Labeller in a Default Labeller?

Tags: build-automation, cruisecontrol.net, ccnet-config

I am working with CruiseControl.NET, and I need to set a label with a specific format:

- SomeText_Date_Revision

With the **Default Labeller** I can put some text and the date in the **prefix** and in addition I get the build number.

But I need a number like the revision number in the **Date Labeller**. This revision number starts from 1 every day while the build number is an ongoing count which increases with every build.

I need to somehow get a prefix to the Date Labeller or I need to get a number like the revision number in the Default Labeller.

How do I achieve this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I share a label value between multiple CruiseControl.NET builds?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1706601/how-do-i-share-a-label-value-between-multiple-cruisecontrol-net-builds)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the shipped labellers do not fit your needs you can simply write our one labeller with a few lines of code.

Ruben Willems has written some blog posts on how to implement your own labeller:

- [Continous Installation: knowing the version](http://rubenwillems.blogspot.be/2009/02/continous-installation-knowing-version.html)
- [Yet another trigger: installTrigger](http://rubenwillems.blogspot.be/2011/07/yet-another-trigger-installtrigger.html)

You can also take a look at the standard labellers that comes with CruiseControl.NET here:
[CruiseControl.NET Labellers source code](https://github.com/ccnet/CruiseControl.NET/tree/master/project/core/label)